# How to get Unique Device ID for Amazon Kindle Fire

Tags: android, udid, kindle-fire

To get the Unique Device ID on Android phones/tablets, we use the following:

```
((TelephonyManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).getDeviceId()
```

But for Kindle Fire, we can't get one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try using the following line:

```
deviceId = Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

This will get the device ID from tablets, the code you're using only works on phones (it will return `null` on tablets)

Answer (score 0):

put

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

then

try this:

```
public String deviceId;
```

then:

```
// ------------- get UNIQUE device ID
        deviceId = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()); // --------
                                                                // backup for
                                                                // tablets etc
        try {
            final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getBaseContext()
                    .getSystemService(Main.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            final String tmDevice, tmSerial, tmPhone, androidId;
            tmDevice = "" + tm.getDeviceId();
            tmSerial = "" + tm.getSimSerialNumber();
            androidId = ""
                    + android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(
                            getContentResolver(),
                            android.provider.Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
            UUID deviceUuid = new UUID(androidId.hashCode(),
                    ((long) tmDevice.hashCode() << 32) | tmSerial.hashCode());
            deviceId = deviceUuid.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("Attention", "Nu am putut sa iau deviceid-ul !?");
        }
        // ------------- END get UNIQUE device ID
```

from here -> [Is there a unique Android device ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id)